# Php Android cross platform encryption

Tags: php, android, encryption

i'm using this code in my Php WebSerice to encrypt and decrypt data:

```
<?php
/**
 * Class that will deal with the encryption of the api
 */
class Encryption
{

    private $KEY = "some key"; //the encryption key

    /**
     * Encrypt data
     * @param $data string the data to encrypt
     * @return string the encrypted data
     */
    public function encrypt($data)
    {
        if (!empty($data))
            return trim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->KEY, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND))));
    }

    /**
     * Decrypt data
     * @param $data string the data to decrypt
     * @return string the decrypted data
     */
    public function decrypt($data)
    {
        if (!empty($data))
            return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->KEY, base64_decode($data), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND)));
    }
}

?>
```

and in my Android application this is my encryption method:

```
    /**
     * api encryption key
     */
    private static final String KEY = Base64.encodeBytes("some key".getBytes());

    /**
     * api's encryption algorithm
     */
    private static final String ALGOITHM = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";  


    /**
     * Encrypt a data string
     * @param data the data string
     * @return an encrypted string
     * @throws Exception when encryption failed 
     */
    public static String encrypt(String data) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(KEY.getBytes(), ALGOITHM);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGOITHM);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] dataBytes = data.getBytes(););
        byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(dataBytes);
        return Base64.encodeBytes(encryptedBytes);
   }
```

but yet the data isn't showing right... any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You fell for [the mcrypt trap](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong).

`MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` isn't AES-256, it's the 256-bit block size variant of Rijndael. AES is always a 128-bit block size even with 256-bit keys.

Look into [libsodium](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/bindings_for_other_languages) instead. There are bindings for Android, iOS, and PHP. If you upgrade to PHP 7.2 or higher, you should have it installed already.